# how to repeat an R command with minor changes? How to make a loop to automate the following code for more variables?

Tags: r

how can i make my code more general? I want to be able to imput fast as many variables as i want.

```
asset1 <- asset_returns_xts[,1]
asset2 <- asset_returns_xts[,2]
asset3 <- asset_returns_xts[,3]
asset4 <- asset_returns_xts[,4]
asset5 <- asset_returns_xts[,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop:

```r
for(i in 1:5){
    assign(paste0("asset", i), asset_returns_xts[,i])  
}
```

Apply family functions (lapply, sapply) may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `list2env`.

```
list2env(setNames(d[1:3], paste0('asset', 1:3)), envir=.GlobalEnv)

ls()
# [1] "asset1" "asset2" "asset3" "d"
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
```